# How to install "RTAQ" package in R

Tags: r, install.packages

How to install "RTAQ" package in R?

I found a website with 4 packages I need, but I can't download "RTAQ" file.(
http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=316 )

This command below is invalid too. 
install.packages("RTAQ", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RTAQ’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)

Answer (score 1):

RTAQ has been archived from CRAN, since CRAN was unable to receive a clean update of the software since November 2012. For details, see the following message on the [CRAN RTAQ page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTAQ/index.html).

If you want to use RTAQ, you'll need to install an older version of R that is compatible with RTAQ, and use RTAQ with that version of R.